# CTRL-O causing terminal to freeze

Tags: terminal, windows, cygwin, freeze, putty

I am using cygwin on Windows 10, to `ssh` to my servers, and recently I noticed that whenever I pressed `CTRL+o` the entire session/cygwin window would freeze up. I tested it out on putty as well and same thing happens. I have also noticed that pressing `CTRL+o` again causes it to unfreeze.

I am pretty sure this did not use to happen before, as I use `nano` text editor usually and `CTRL-o` for saving the file. This is causing a lot of frustration now as every time I try to save a file the whole session gets stuck.

Also I have tried `stty -ixon` command but it did not help and it seems unrelated to `CTRL+s` and `CTRL+q`.

Any ideas what might be causing this and if it can be disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have by any chance NZXT Cam software running? The default hotkey to activate it's overlay is Ctrl+O. Remove the assigned hotkey in NZXT Cam Settings > Overlay and you should be good.

Comment: I do have the NZXT Cam software running. I will try to turn that off and get back to you.

Comment: That was the problem. I am not sure if that is intended behavior of CAM though.

Comment: OMG, I thought smth with servers )))

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html):

```
~ (101) stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

> Special characters:
>   * ***discard*** *CHAR*
>   *CHAR* will toggle ***discarding*** of output

(your settings may differ...)

The manual page says also

> In settings, *CHAR* is taken literally, or coded as in `^c`, `0x37`, `0177` or
>          `127`; special values **`^-`** or ***`undef`*** used to disable special characters.

Comment: Yes that is set to this : `discard = ^O` , is there a way to change that? Also, this started occurring only recently, do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps some update set the value.  You can use `stty` to set any of those to a undef (undefined) value to disable them.

Comment: I disabled it, but the freeze is still happening upon pressing `ctrl+o`